# Complex XPATH With PHP

Tags: php, arrays, xml, xpath, xml-parsing

think about my xml is like this:

```
<products>
 <product>
  <ProductID>252</ProductID>
        <detail>
          <color>red</color>
          <price>$15</price>
        </detail>
        <detail>
          <color>blue</color>
          <price>$25</price>
        </detail>
 </product>
</products>
```

I need to get price value of ProductID=252's RED MODEL

i tried this; but could not get the price value:

```
$q = $xml->xpath('/products/product[ProductID="252"]/detail[color="red"]');
echo $q['price'];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a few separate small problems here. Your XPath query includes the root `<products>` tag, which isn't needed if you've imported this into SimpleXML. The query can just begin with `product/...`

Next, `xpath()` returns an array of matching elements, even if there is only one of them. So `$q` refers to the full result set, rather than the first match. The match you're looking for is the array's first element, under key `0`

Finally, you're referring to the price using an array index - `['price']`. This is used to fetch an attribute of a tag, rather than a child node. If you want the text content of the `<price>` element, you should use the object-access operator `->`, and cast to a string.

The full code should look something like this:

```
$q = $xml->xpath('product[ProductID="252"]/detail[color="red"]')[0];

echo (string) $q->price;
// $15
```

See https://eval.in/936371 for a full example.